# Launching Typescript app in Visual Studio Code throws error "Cannot find module 'electron'"

Tags: typescript, electron, visual-studio-code

When attempting to launch a typescript application in Visual Studio Code (vs code) I'm getting the error "Cannot find module 'electron'". The project I'm trying to launch is [black-screen](https://github.com/shockone/black-screen) which I have cloned from github.

This error is thrown on the following statement:

`import {ipcMain, nativeImage} from "electron";`

(on line 3 of the file https://github.com/shockone/black-screen/blob/master/src/main/Main.ts#l3)

I can transpile the application using the typescript-compiler (tsc) and no errors are generated, and can see the compiled javascript in the folder I expect (src/bin/). I can also start the application successfully using npm ("npm start").

Below are the relevant project configuration files:

1. src/tsconfig.json

   ```
   {
       "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es6",
       "module": "commonjs",
       "noImplicitAny": true,
       "removeComments": true,
       "preserveConstEnums": true,
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "experimentalDecorators": true,
       "noEmitOnError": true,
       "pretty": true,
       "jsx": "react",
       "sourceMap": true,
       "outDir": "bin"
     }
   }
   ```
2. .vscode/tasks.json file
   Note. Executing the equivalent command in a terminal "tsc --project src --moduleResolution node" generates the transpiled js code with no errors or warnings.

   ```
   {
       "version": "0.1.0",
       "command": "tsc",
       "isShellCommand": true,
       "showOutput": "silent",
       "args": ["--project", "src", "--moduleResolution", "node"],
       "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
   }
   ```
3. .vscode/launch.json

   ```
   {
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
               "name": "Launch Black-Screen",
               "type": "node",
               "request": "launch",
               "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/main/Main.ts",
               "stopOnEntry": false,
               "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
               "sourceMaps": true,
               "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/src/bin"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

Btw. the project structure is:

```
|.vscode/
|-- launch.json
|-- tasks.json
|decorators/
|...
|node_modules/
|-- bin/
|-- abbrev/
|-- acorn/
|README/
|-- <image files>
|src/
|-- bin/
|-- main/
|---- Main.ts
|---- Menu.ts
|...
|-- tsconfig.json
|...
|stylesheets/
|...
|test/
|...
|typings/
|...
|.babelrc
|.gitignore
|.npmrc
|...
|gulfile.bable.js
|package.json
|...
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have a definition file (`.d.ts`) for Electron? Without that, the Typescript language service won't be able to tell that it exists.

Comment: In fact, I've just noticed that the repo you cloned has a `typings.json` - try running `npm install typings -g` then `typings install` in the project directory.

Comment: Thanks Joe. After I saw Basarat's answer I checked and saw the "typings" directory was already in the repository files. I did try installing typings (`npm install -g typings` & `typings install`).

Comment: However after running these commands and recompiling i saw the error - `error TS2300: Duplicate identifier <variable-name>` for files "typings/browser/ambient/github-electron/github-electron.d.ts" and "typings/browser/ambient/electron/electron.d.ts".

Comment: This is due to them providing separate definition files for server-side and client-side - you can find instructions on fixing the issue here: https://github.com/typings/typings#maindts-and-browserdts. I'm not sure which one you should exclude for an Electron project, so you might have to try both.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Adding the "exclude" section to the tsconfig.json file (and excluding "typings/browser.d.ts" & "typings/browser") did indeed fix the duplicate identifier errors I saw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the error with the electron module not being recognized by the debugger. The problem was due to the electron application not starting prior to my application being launched.

I found a stackoverflow question and linked blog post which addressed this issue -
[Debugging Electron-Atom script with Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31429394/debugging-electron-atom-script-with-visual-studio-code)  /
http://www.mylifeforthecode.com/a-better-way-to-launch-electron-from-visual-studio-code/

Adding the line `"runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/electron"` to my "launch.json" file started electron before the debugger launched.

My final "launch.json" file was:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Black-Screen",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/main/Main.ts",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/src/bin",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/electron"
        }
    ]
}
```

The debugger is stopping at the breakpoints I set. I noticed the performance of electron is much slower using the debugger but that's another issue I'll work through :)

Comment: Using `electron-prebuilt@0.37.6` I need to use the following: `"runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/cli.js"`

Answer (score 1):

The project contains https://github.com/shockone/black-screen/blob/master/typings/main/ambient/github-electron/github-electron.d.ts and the module is declared : https://github.com/shockone/black-screen/blob/master/typings/main/ambient/github-electron/github-electron.d.ts#L1884

Suspect wrong line:

```
"args": ["--project", "src", "--moduleResolution", "node"],
```

Change to :

```
"args": ["-p", "./src"],
```

As that has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Thanks Basarat - I tried the new typescript arguments in both the command line '.vscode/tasks.json' file and from the command line. Unfortunately I saw the same error as before when attempting to launch the application in vs code.